# ng-view changes checkbox element's css

Tags: css, angularjs, checkbox, user-agent, ng-view

In my angularjs application, the partials into `<ng-view>` element get my form's checkbox's css changed to the default css for the user agent.

When I retrieve the checkbox directly without going through the `$routeProvider` I get the checkbox element rendered with my custom css.
Outside the `ng-view` element, the checkbox elements renders just fine with the custom css.

Is there a way to render the custom css for checkbox element and not the user agent's default css for that?

Comment: what you are saying cannot be the case, you will have reanalyze the sequence of events..

Comment: Your CSS rules perhaps just didn't match, in the `ng-view` case.

Comment: @HarishR: Why could it not be the case? Its simple, I have the checkbox element inside the ng-view element overridden with default css of the user agent for that. But it renders just fine outside `ng-view` element.

Comment: can you share the css classes you are using..

Comment: @HarishR: I am using uniform sexy forms with jquery at http://uniformjs.com. Could I be seeing this difference due to this plugin not initialized properly with jQuery with AngularJS? Is there a different way to initialize jQuery plugins differently when using angularjs with `ng-view`?

Comment: Where is the initialization of uniform js?
If it's in a directive or in a controller out of the ng-view content, the checkbox cannot be initialized after each navigation.
When the path change, the ng-view content is deleted and replaced.

Comment: Yes, the initialization was the issue. Had to do the initialization in a directive.